# javac error inconvertible types java.lang.Double

Tags: java, compiler-errors, terminal, javac

I found very similar questions to mine here, but I cannot work my problem out with the other posts. Sorry for the double posting maybe...

I am trying to run my code in my terminal but I am getting a javac error, even though my code seems to be fine in Eclipse.

```
      public class MinHeap<E extends Comparable<E>> {
         List<E> h = new ArrayList<E>();
         ArrayList<E> arrayPostingsList = new ArrayList<E>();
     //some more code

        public double remove() {
          E removedNode = h.get(0);
          E lastNode = h.remove(h.size() - 1);
          percolateDown(0, lastNode);
           //this seems to be the problem
          return (Double) removedNode;
      }
```

This is the error I get

```
   MinHeap.java:40: inconvertible types
   found   : E
   required: java.lang.Double
   Double B = (Double) removedNode;
                    ^
   1 error
```

Any tips?

With all your input I have changed the return type and it is working fine.

```
         public E remove() {
           E removedNode = h.get(0);
           E lastNode = h.remove(h.size() - 1);
           percolateDown(0, lastNode);

         return removedNode;
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Double` is a wrapper class, while `double` is a primitive type. They're not the same, and the compiler will get mad if you try to return an object when it needs a primitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do

```
public class MinHeap<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    List<E> h = new ArrayList<E>();
    ArrayList<E> arrayPostingsList = new ArrayList<E>();

    // some more code
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MinHeap<Double> testHeap = new MinHeap<Double>();
        testHeap.add(2.3); // auto-boxing
        System.out.println(testHeap.remove()); //unboxing

    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        return h.add(e);
    }

    public E remove() {
        E removedNode = h.get(0);
        E lastNode = h.remove(h.size() - 1);

        // this seems to be the problem
        return removedNode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the element that is held by the MinHeap is of type `E`, you are removing an element of the same type and so the return type of `remove()` method should also be `E`.

When you declare an instance of MinHeap holding `Double` type objects, then the return type would become `Double` anyway and you can write it as follows:

```
MinHeap<Double> minHeap = ....
....
Double removedValue = minHeap.remove();
```

Your code is giving compile error because it doesn't make sense for a MinHeap holding String objects, right?

Answer (score 0):

**I think your eclipse is using different java version than one available in command line.** I guess you are using `Java 1.7.x` in eclipse and some lower version(e.g. `1.6.x`) in command line. Please set the same version of java in command line and check. It should behave the same.

Try checking java version on command line by using `java -version`. I am positive, its JDK 1.6 or below as above code compiles fine with JDK 1.7 through command line as well as eclipse but gives the mentioned error with JDK 1.6.